# When I try to use XPath to click a button using C# Selenium it doesn't work

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I tried to click on a button by using the buttons XPath in C# Selenium. But in C# it shows the below error. I don't know what to do I am new this platform. So kindly help me with this.

[image: Image of the Error]

Answer (score 1):

Nothing but I just removed the double quotes. Instead I used the single quotes for **[@id='content']**.

```
IWebElement search = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='content']/div/form/div[2]/div[4]/a"));
search.Click();
```